# SD card write speed becomes 0 when used space reaches 50 MB

Tags: partitioning, sd-card

The size of the SD card is 64 GB but when I copy files it stops when the used space is 50 MB and the write speed becomes 0 and stays. Tried ejecting and putting back still I cannot copy further than 50 MB. I scanned and checked the sectors using PartitionGuru and all the sectors were normal.

Tried `diskpart` and when I select the disk and execute clean it gives me "data cyclic redundancy check" error.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Is this a new card you have just bought or an old card that has worked in the past?

Comment: It's a new card

Comment: From eBay (or similar) or from a reputable source? There are many "fake" SD cards that are actually a lower capacity card that has been hacked to appear as a larger card.

Comment: No bought from a reputable local store. (G.Skill 64GB Micro SDXC Flash Memory Card with SD Adapter)

Comment: It's still probably a fake.  Not necessarily the local store's fault, but see if you can return it, or perhaps go to G.Skill for the warranty replacement.  If it's a fake, G.Skill has an interest in finding out who's distributing fakes in their name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gskill offered me 3 replacements and with everything i encountered the issue. Then they had asked the local shop to send the memory cards to analyze and after that they gave me a refund saying that it's a compatibility issue with my laptop which is an HP stream.

Answer (score 0):

**First off**, try using an antimalware such as [Hitman Pro](http://download.cnet.com/HitmanPro-3-64-bit/3000-2239_4-75110395.html), maybe a malware that has more access on FAT file system prevents you to copy files. *If still doesn't solve problem*, **Secondly,** Run the CHKDSK Utility

Open the command prompt. You must run CHKDSK commands as an administrator to have the necessary privileges to execute the scan.
Type “chkdsk /f x:” into the command prompt. The letter “x” should be replaced with the letter name of the drive you’d like to run the scan on. Press enter.
Wait for the scan to complete. Once finished CHKDSK will give you a report and restart your computer. If CHKDSK is able to fix the issue this is all you need to do.
If the repair seems to get stuck and never finish it is likely because you have many damaged files and CHKDSK will not be able to repair them.

Over time your hard disk may develop minor file corruptions and other small errors through a number of different means. CHKDSK can fix many small issues but cannot address more serious problems. *If still not...,*
**Thirdly,** Use a 3rd Party Disk Utility
Install a free disk utility. HDDScan and SeaTools will provide an alternative to CHKDSK and may help solve the issue when CHKDSK fails.
Open the utility and run the scan. Follow the instructions to run a scan on the drive that gave you the cyclic redundancy check error.
Repair all the issues. It's important to let the repairs run to completion, and depending on the state of your hard disk this repair could take more than 2 hours.
Re-scan your computer.

Comment: Tried chkdsk and it tells me that there are no errors. I'll try with the third party tools you mentioned and check.

Comment: Did you check and ensure that there isn't any malware?

Comment: Not yet. I will check that as well.

Comment: No malware and Hddscan read is also working

Comment: Then, unfortunately i must say the same as  @Mokubai said; I also have faced with a such fake SD cards or USB Flashes. Next time you should just test before purchasing.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you have a fake SD card. Try this software to test it: https://sosfakeflash.wordpress.com/2008/09/02/h2testw-14-gold-standard-in-detecting-usb-counterfeit-drives/

Symptoms like this are often due to someone modifying the card to report 64GB of space, when in fact it has considerably less. After a short time writing to the card starts to corrupt the data to it.

Even though you say the card is from a reputable brand and store, it's still worth checking. Some of the fakes look quite good and come in retail packaging these days.

Comment: Checked after 67mb it gives me "Error writing file 'H:\1.h2w', offset 0x4300000."

Comment: It's a fake card, or broken. Take it back to the shop.